# Two Dimensional Arrays in Java Lang

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

My question is,can i check a place if null,or set a place to null in two dimensional String array with my way.

```
String [][] xx=new String [][]
public void set(int a,int b)
  {
 xx[a][b]=null;//setting null
 }
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 if(xx[a][b]==null)//check if null
  ///some codes
```

İs it possible?Or if wrong,how to do it.?Regards..

Comment: You would know if you try it.

Comment: Did you try it and it didn't work? If not, then it should, and something else may be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Since this is an array of objects (which is really just an array of memory addresses, you can indeed set them to null as that would be setting the address to 0).  However if you have a two dimensional array of a primitive type, such as an int, then you cannot set positions to null.

Comment: i cannot apply to strings as well then?..so how i can do it.deleting it with for loop?

Comment: It will work fine for String objects.  Any standard type that starts with a capital letter is an object (and you should follow this convention for your own classes).  Any standard type that starts with a lower-case letter, such as `int` or `double`, is a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify how many elements are in your array, and you don't have to manually set the elemnts to null.

```
public class Dim2AR
{
    // String [][] xx = new String [][];
    String [][] xx = new String [20][20];

    public void set (int a, int b)
    {
        xx[a][b] = null; 
    }

    public void set (int a, int b, String v)
    {
        xx[a][b] = v; 
    }

    public Dim2AR ()
    {
        check (3, 3);
        set (3, 3);
        check (4, 3);
        set (4, 3, "foo");
        check (4, 3);
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new Dim2AR ();
    }

    public void check (int a, int b)
    {
        if (xx[a][b] != null) System.out.println ("> " + xx[a][b]);
        else System.out.println ("-");  
    }
}
```